# Is it possible to permanently show notifications on my screen?

Tags: scripts, notification, notify-send

With the command `notify-send`, it's possible to show a notification on screen for a small amount of time. But I'd like to have a specific notification on my screen for an undetermined amount of time. I'm creating a script that is initiated and terminated by the user, for me it'd be useful to have a command that activates the notification and then deactivates it after my script is finished. The pseudocode would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

activatenotification "my text"

# my script commands

deactivatenotification
```

Is it possible to do? Is there such a command line tool or can I do something like that using `notify-send`?

Comment: `notify-send`  is built in such way that the notifications do have to exit. What you can use is `zenity` to show popups. These can stay on screen indefinitely. They're small GUI windows. So you can either close or kill them.  Does that sound like something that you're looking for ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I'd like to keep using the computer while I see the notification on my screen. I think that `zenity` doesn't allow me to navigate through other windows while it's open, does it?

Comment: Zenity dialog windows are just like any other application windows. You can still put them in the background or minimize them and keep doing other things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your issue is with the short duration of the `notify-send` alert, then you can set the urgency level of an alert to '*critical*'. This would produce a persistent notification which you'll have to dismiss manually.

Use the following format

```
notify-send -u critical "Header" "Body text"
```

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work. Using notify-send 0.7.8 with mate-notification-daemon on Ubuntu 19.10 with i3wm

Comment: Still works fine here with `notify-send` v0.7.9 on vanilla Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Changed to dunst. This works. Thanks for the prompt reply!